# Meteor update collection doesn't refresh on client

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection which has style properties which I iterate through and apply to the corresponding element:

```
// server side
Meteor.publish('elements', function(){
  return Elements.find();
});

//client side
Meteor.subscribe("elements");

setupElements = function () {
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    var elements = Elements.find({user: currentUserId}).fetch();
    elements.forEach(function(e){
    var elementId = e._id;
    eval("document.getElementById('" + elementId + "').removeAttribute(\"style\")");
    var width = e.width;
      for (var i in width) {
        eval("document.getElementById('" + elementId + "').style.width"= \"" + width[i] + "\"");
      }
    });
}

Template.element.rendered = function() {
  if(!this._rendered) {
    this._rendered = true;

    // iterate through element and apply width style to each
    setupElements();
  }
}

// template
<template name="element">
  {{#each element}}
    <div id="{{_id}}" class="element">{{text}}</div>
  {{/each}}
  <button id="change-style">Change style</button>
</template>
```

The template renders and applies the corresponding width to each element. However, when I trigger an update like below:

```
'click #change-style': function() {
    Meteor.call('updateElements'); // assume server-method successfully updated all elements
    setupElements(); // thought this will fetch new style and re-apply
  },
```

The documents are updated in the database but the template/view does not react to the change until I refresh the page or trigger the event again. Seems like the database is not refreshed on the client-side when the server updates it. Wondering what's the right setup to make the re-apply style reactive, or if there is a way to force refresh template.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wha... Why do you eval()? And the eval() string seems to go way off. Are you following some kind of evil tutorial?

Comment: @Poyli Keep in mind javascript on the client is asynchronous. What's going on is `setupElements` is running before the call's tasks are done.

Comment: @Kyll that's just my rough attempt to iterate through each object, grab the corresponding id and apply its style properties. Need to refactor that part but will do it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are probably better ways to do what you're doing by using standard reactive html & JQuery. In the context of your exact question:

Javascript is asynchronous. The `setupElements` fires before the results arrive from the server. Simply fire it in the `.call` callback:

```
Meteor.call('updateElements', setupElements);
```

Comment: I see, I thought somehow the client maintains a outdated version of collection but it's simply fired before the update is ready.

Comment: And yea the current setup can definitely be refactored, I'll look into that separately.

Thanks a lot!